# What type of account is used for individuals to trade government issued bonds directly with Treasury?

Tags: united-states, government-bonds

Here is my understanding - an account at a financial institution that allows an individual to trade corporate bonds is a **brokerage** account.

Here is my question - an account held by an individual at Treasury Direct to trade government issued bonds...what type of account is that?

Comment: A 'Treasure Direct Account' - there is no officially defined formal nomenclature. Financial institutions name them as they like.

Comment: For what purpose? Depending on who's asking, there's no "official" classification of accounts.

Comment: 'trade/trading' normally means on the secondary market, which TD does NOT support. Besides cash TD supports ONLY noncompetitive purchase at issue and redemption at maturity; this is in the broader category 'investment'. A brokerage account can trade _all_ kinds of bonds: corporates, (so-called) municipals, and (marketable) treasuries -- plus other things like stocks, ETFs, UITs, PTPs, ....